# Get a Random Boolean by Percentage using tkinter

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, tkinter, random

Please could you explain how to use tkinter to make an `Entry` widget that passes a percentage value to the function below e.g. the user enters `60` into the input field which then passes the user’s value to the `percent = 55` argument so it updates in real time to whatever value the user types in?

```
def reset(percent=55):
    prob = random.randrange(0,100)
    if prob > percent:
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
print(reset(15))
```

N.B Matplotlib, random and NumPy are being imported.

Tried using the input(), int() and str() functions but the IDLE still produces errors. Editing the 'percent=' argument too much causes the program to crash.

The 'percent=' argument only seems to accept the format: percent=number

Comment: can u put the error in the question?

Comment: There seems to be an indentation problem in the code you posted.

Comment: Your code is working on Python 3.12.0rc3.

Comment: Is the problem that the code runs `reset("60")` not `reset(60)`, passing a sting not a numeric?  If it is, there needs to be a function that converts anything the user can enter into the `Entry` into an acceptable `int` before passing it to `reset`.